# 8 Queens - calculating number of queens per row

Tags: java

I am tackling the 8 queens problem, and I am struggling with counting the number of queens that are on each row. Queens are represented by 1's. My program initially places all 8 queens randomly on the board to start, but there is something wrong with my results (which I call h for heuristic. For example, if I have only one 1 on a row, h should = 0 ( because this means no conflicts), but if there are two 1's on a row, then my h should = 1 for that row. after I iterate through all of the rows it is to return the total h value, but I am getting numbers that don't make sense. When I run it, I get h = 0, even though I may have 2 or 3 queens residing on the same row. What am I doing wrong?
(if you need me to put up all of my code, I am more than happy to)

```
public void computeHeuristic(){  //calculate heuristic value for whole board rows and diags

    int h = 0;
    int row = 0;
    int queen = 0;
    //int numQueens = 0;
    //Rows

    while(row <= 7 ){//increment row upto 7
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){             
            h += board[row][j]; 

            row++;      
        }
    }
    System.out.print("h: " + h + "\n");
}
```

Comment: What will be the value of  `h` if there are more than two `1`s in a row?

Comment: based on rules you mentioned, you need int[8] h and before you increment the rows ( row++) test if the h[row] > 1 => h[row]=1 else h[row]=0 ( which means row has only one queen or no queen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find any logic in your basic code:

```
while(row <= 7 ){//increment row upto 7
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){             
        h += board[row][j]; 

        row++;      
    }
}
```

here even if you put the `row++` in the outer loop you would be summing up the contents of all the cells of the 8X8 array. As there are 8 1s and 56 0s, `h` would always result to 8 whatever may be the placements of the 1s

in order to check how many rows have more than one 1s in a row try the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    int check = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){             
        check += board[i][j]; 
    }
    if(check > 1){
        h += check - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: >h: 2

0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: erg, I cant get it to show right. I got h = 2, but in the first row I have 3 (1's), and in the last row I have 3 (1's) so my h should be 4

Comment: yes that is what your required - the first and the last rows have 3 1s in each row so h is 2 for the 2 rows where there are more than 1 1s in a row.

Comment: So maybe I am asking the wrong question then. if in row 1 I have 2 1s, then row 1 = 1, I will iterate through each row counting the total 1s only if there is more than one. at the end I will get a total. so if for row 1 i get 2, row 2 i get 0, row 3 i get 3, then my overall h will be 5

Comment: *if I have only one 1 on a row, h should = 0 ( because this means no conflicts), but if there are **two 1's on a row, then my h should = 1** for that row* - how does it mean it should be 4?

Comment: if I have a 4x4 2d array filled with 1s and 0s. 1s represent queens. I need to count how many conflicting queens I have per row for all four rows.

Comment: `while(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)` ?

Answer (score 0):

> When I run it, I get h = 0

Most probably the first row is not initialize with any `1` and you are checking only the first row, because your while loops body will iterate only one time as you increment `row` inside the for loop,

```
for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){             
    h += board[row][j]; 

    row++; 
    ^^^^^     
}
```

So after the iteration of `for` loops complete, `row` becomes `8`, and hence the while loop not going to loop again.

From a wild guess I think you are going to update `h` from `0` to `1` if any row contains more than one `1` (e.g. two or more `1`s in a row).

So try this:

```
int singleRowCount = -1;
for(int row = 0; row < 8; row++){
    for(int col = 0; col < 8; col++){             
        singleRowCount += board[row][col]; 
    }
    if(singleRowCount > 0)
        h += singleRowCount;
    singleRowCount = -1;
}
```

[Check live here.](http://ideone.com/jzimDn)

Comment: if he did it your way he would always get `h: 8`

Comment: @Blip, I hope someday you will tell me the reason why my edited code will give always `h = 0`. But as I can't wait long enough for your response, so [run live this](http://ideone.com/jzimDn).

Comment: suppose the case is the first row contains all the 1s. So after the 1st iteration you would have h as 7. But for each of the next 7 iterations will return `singleRowCount` as -1. So `(7 + (7 * -1))` will be 0. You can try out any combination it will always return 0.